# Hibernate OneToMany relation is not persisted

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin

I have the following Spring Boot code

```kotlin
@Entity
class Contact(
  public val name:String,
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact", cascade=[ALL])public val phones:Phone,
  @Id @GenerateValue(strategy=AUTO)public val id:Int?)


@Entity
class Phone(
  public val num:String,
  @ManyToOne(cascade=[ALL])public val contact:Contact,
  @Id @GenerateValue(strategy=AUTO)public val id:Int?)


@RestController
class Rest(private val phoneRepo:PhoneRepo,private val contactRepo:ContactRepo){
  @PostMapping("/contact")
  fun postContact(@ModelAttribute c:Contact,@RequestParams("phonesId",required=false) phones:List<Phone>){
    c.phones=phoneRepo.findAllById(if(phones==null){arrayListOf()}else{phones})
    contactRepo.save(c)
}
```

That gets called by this html code

```html
<form method=post action=/contact >
  <input name=name type=text>
  <select name=phonesId multiple>
<option value=1>some contact number</option>
<!-- some other options generated based on the Phone entries in the db-->
</select>
<input type=hidden name=id value=1>
</form>
```

However if I submit the above form the phones field is not updated.

I tried:

1. Adding cascade=ALL
2. setting the contact field in Phone and then persist those entities, but that gives me an IllegalStateException

Comment: To be clear when I tried to persist the phones entries I did with `phoneRepo.saveAll(c.phones)`